# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'

Tags: python, flask, import, module, path

Pycharm imports works correctly, but when I execute test_settings.py in the terminal, I have this error:

> ImportError while importing test module '/home/ed/PycharmProjects/TTime/tests/test_settings.py'.
>
> Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
>
> Traceback:
>   tests/test_settings.py:3: in 
>       from ttime import app, db
>   E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttime'

Here is my Flask project structure. I tried to include **init**.py in the main folder and in the tests folder, but nothing changes. It seems like somethings is wrong with python paths.

```
.
├── config.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── runserver.py
├── tests
│   ├── functional
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── pytest.ini
│   ├── test_settings.py
│   └── unit
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_models.py
└── ttime
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── routes.py
    ├── static
    └── templates
        ├── base.html
        └── index.html
```

Comment: are you sure that it isnt simply a typo? check the imports in test_settings.py.you are importing a module named `ttime`

Comment: this is the import statement `from ttime.models import User, Timesheet`

Comment: /home/ed/PycharmProjects/TTime/ttime

Comment: maybe you can fix it by using`from ..ttime.models import User, Timesheet` or `from ...ttime.models import User, Timesheet` not sure

Comment: I got this: Traceback:
tests/test_settings.py:5: in <module>
    from ..ttime.models import User, Timesheet
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3